# vb.net and ms access loading image path

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i want to all the values in column "imgPath" to load as picture in image column "img" but this is the error I'm getting.[image]

how to fix this?

i have a table like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We need code and errors as text, not pictures.  Your Autos window shows you the problem - `row.Cells("imgPath).Value` is Nothing and you can use `ToString` with `Nothing`.  Each row doesnt need its own column either

Comment: oh I'm sorry, well I'm on a rush that's why i thought i can put it up like that. my bad.

Comment: but why my row.cells("imgPath").value is Nothing, but it has value on my database as shown in the second picture. and when i try to load it all first in datagrid view it loads all but when i try to read the image path to put it in image column then it has an error message like that.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]